# fputcsv display leading zeros

Tags: php, csv

I'm using a PHP script to generate an excel CSV file from a result-set query.
All works fine but when I read my excel file, I can not display leading zeros.

This is my code:

```
$rows = $this->Query($sql);

$filename = "/www/zendsvr/htdocs/Project/public/report.xls";
$realPath = realpath( $filename );

$filename = realpath( $filename );
$handle = fopen( $filename, "w" );
$finalData = array();

for( $i = 0; $i < count( $rows ); $i++ ) {
    $finalData[] = array( utf8_decode( $rows[$i]->CODE ) );
}

foreach ( $finalData AS $finalRow ) {
    fputcsv( $handle, $finalRow, "\t" );
}

fclose( $handle );
```

If I make a `var_dump()` of `$finalData[]` I see the correct value, for example '000198', '000199', '000200' but the same value in my XLS file is 198,199,200

How can I also display leading zeros in the XLS file?

Comment: How do you open your XLS file ? I mean XLS editor have automatic format functions, so be sure that's not your editor which removes the `0` of your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data is saved correctly, it is Excel who is trying to be smart.

Use the Excel import data wizard instead of opening the file directly (rename the .csv file to .txt if necessary). On the import wizard, choose the data type of the column as "text" instead of "general":

[image: Text import wizard step 3]

Comment: In case you are exporting a CSV file which is used in another import process by end users, we need to warn then. Then again an oversight causes other consequences. I'm still hopeful to find a way to go around this forced Microsoft Excel feature!

Answer (score 28):

To add to DemoUser's approach:

The `\t` approach worked for me however with a slight change

```
$column_data = "\t000543";
```

Adding the `\t` solved my problem of having the leading zero's disappear, even though the CSV was correct and Excel was 'wrong' the `\t` worked in keeping the leading zeros intact when displaying in excel.

Comment: simple solution saved my day.

Comment: @bhawani using single or double quotes?

Answer (score 12):

I was surprised after so many years no-one came with a working solution.

Here's what worked for me:

```php
$records = [
    ['name' => 'John', 'phone' => '01234567'],
    ['name' => 'Jane', 'phone' => '01234569'],
];

$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($file, ['Name', 'Phone N°']);

foreach ($records as $record) {
    fputcsv($file, [$record['name'], "=\"" . $record['phone'] . "\""]);
}
```

Comment: This should be selected as answered question

Answer (score 3):

Try casting it to string like:

```
fputcsv($fp, (string) $val);
```

OR, Opening XLS file will truncate leading 0 so try adding /t before zero to avoid 0 truncation while creating your row values.

Comment: i've tryed but alwais same problem!