# PHP : Convert Number to String while writing in CSV

Tags: php, csv

```
$array = array(
    array("Id" => 0001 , "Name" => "Punit"),
    array("Id" => 0002 , "Name" => "Pratik"),
    array("Id" => 0003 , "Name" => "Milan"),
    array("Id" => 0004 , "Name" => "Pritesh"),
    array("Id" => 0005 , "Name" => "Kunjan"),
    array("Id" => 0006 , "Name" => "Hemant"),
    array("Id" => 0007 , "Name" => "Ravi"),
    array("Id" => 0008 , "Name" => "Mitesh"),
    array("Id" => 0009 , "Name" => "Ankur")
);

$contents = "Id,Name\n";
foreach ($array as $id => $call) {    
    $contents.=str_replace(",", " ", $call['Id']) . ",";
    $contents.=str_replace(",", " ", $call['Name']) . "\n";;
}


header('Content-type:application/csv');
//header to make force download the file
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="ConferenceReport-NBCU' . date('d-m-Yh:i:s') . '.csv"');
print $contents;
```

Above is my code to generate a CSV file,
as you can see there are Digits given in the Key `Id` inside the array.

Problem is when I try to write the Key `$call['Id']` in the CSV file it become like this

```
Id  Name
1   Punit
2   Pratik
3   Milan
4   Pritesh
5   Kunjan
6   Hemant
7   Ravi
```

`0001 , 0002` are the numbers coming from the database

I want to keep them as it is while writing into the CSV file.

I tried `(string)$call['Id']` , `"".$call['Id'].""`  but nothing works.

Comment: bad structure if ids are like `0001,0002` in db

Comment: yeah , but i did not do it, :-D , my problem is  Project is live and i can not change it now.. already lacs of records . .

Comment: Refer to this: http://superuser.com/questions/431637/why-is-excel-removing-leading-leading-zeros-when-displaying-csv-data

Comment: just use `sprintf("%04d",$call['Id'])`

Comment: @Thamilan ,  not working  :-(

Comment: Please try this. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078531/fputcsv-display-leading-zeros>

Comment: Please try this link, [Leading Zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078531/fputcsv-display-leading-zeros)

Comment: @Anant , no buddy  still struggling ,  :-)

Comment: where?let us know

Answer (score 0):

The numbers 0001, 0002 ... which begins with 0 are basically Octal numbers in php and octal numbers have representation of [0-7]+ So there cann't be any valid number like 0008 0009 and compiler will throw compile error. The recommended solution will be to store these numbers as String in database if you want trailing zeroes also.